# Check infinite number of self generated urls for validity, safe response if valid (http 200)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I would like to check an infinite number of self generated URLs for validity, and if valid safe body of response in a file. URLs look like this: https://mydomain.com/ + random string (e.g. https://mydomain.com/ake3t) and I want to generate them using the alphabet "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-" and just brute force try out all possibilities.

I wrote a script in python but as I am an absolute beginner here it was very slow! As I need something very very fast I tried to use scrapy as I thought it was meant for exactly this kind of job.

The problem now is I cannot find out how to dynamically generate URLs on the fly, I cannot generate them beforehand as it is not a fixed number of them.

Could somebody please show me how to achieve this or recommend me another tool or library even better suited for this job?

UPDATE:
This is the script I used, but I think it is slow. What worries me the most is that it gets slower if I use more than one Thread (specified in threadsNr)

```
import threading, os
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error 

threadsNr   = 1                                    
dumpFolder    = '/tmp/urls/'               
charSet     = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-' 
Url_pre    = 'http://vorratsraum.com/'
Url_post    = 'alwaysTheSameTail'

# class that generate the words
class wordGenerator ():

    def __init__(self, word, charSet):
        self.currentWord = word
        self.charSet = charSet

    # generate the next word set that word as currentWord and return the word
    def nextWord (self):
        self.currentWord = self._incWord(self.currentWord)
        return self.currentWord

    # generate the next word
    def _incWord(self, word):
        word = str(word)                        # convert to string

        if word == '':                          # if word is empty 
            return self.charSet[0]              # return first char from the char set
        wordLastChar = word[len(word)-1]        # get the last char
        wordLeftSide = word[0:len(word)-1]      # get word without the last char
        lastCharPos  = self.charSet.find(wordLastChar)  # get position of last char in the char set

        if (lastCharPos+1) < len(self.charSet):         # if position of last char is not at the end of the char set
            wordLastChar = self.charSet[lastCharPos+1]  # get next char from the char set

        else:                                           # it is the last char
            wordLastChar = self.charSet[0]              # reset last char to have first character from the char set
            wordLeftSide = self._incWord(wordLeftSide)  # send left site to be increased

        return wordLeftSide + wordLastChar      # return the next word


class newThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        global exitThread
        global wordsTried
        global newWord
        global hashList

        while exitThread == False:
            part = newWord.nextWord()                # generate the next word to try
            url = Url_pre + part + Url_post

            wordsTried = wordsTried + 1
            if wordsTried == 1000: # just for testing how fast it is
                exitThread = True
            print( 'trying ' + part)          # display the word
            print( 'At URL ' + url)

            try:
                req = urllib.request.Request(url)
                req.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
                resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
                result = resp.read()
                found(part, result)
            except urllib.error.URLError as err:
                if err.code == 404:
                    print('Page not found!')
                elif err.code == 403:
                    print('Access denied!')
                else:
                    print('Something happened! Error code', err.code)
            except urllib.error.URLError as err:
                print('Some other error happened:', err.reason)
        resultFile.close()

def found(part, result):
    global exitThread
    global resultFile

    resultFile.write(part +"\n")

    if not os.path.isdir(dumpFolder + part):
        os.makedirs(dumpFolder + part)

    print('Found Part = '  + part)

wordsTried = 0                            
exitThread = False                              # flag to kill all threads
newWord = wordGenerator('',charSet);           # word generator

if not os.path.isdir(dumpFolder):
    os.makedirs(dumpFolder)

resultFile = open(dumpFolder + 'parts.txt','a')      # open file for append    

for i in range(threadsNr):
    newThread().start()
```

Comment: If you post your python script, someone might be able to point out simple ways to improve its performance.

Comment: Infinite number, really? There's no way that can be done in any finite amount of time...

Comment: :) I know that it won't finish within a finite amount of time when I want to try an infinite number. But still this is not a matter of speed as it still could try urls twice as fast...

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky it can be done if the time needed for each url is infinitesimal :-)

Comment: @Hernan: perhaps, if the limit of total time required converges to a finite value ;-) But even in that case you'd need an infinite amount of energy to drive a processor with infinite clock speed.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check "an infinite number of URLs" without it being "very slow", beginner or no.

The time your scraper is taking is almost certainly dominated by the response time of the server you're accessing, not by the efficiency of your script.

What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Even if the server (it's my own, so doesn't matter how much requests I send) is the limiting factor, can't I do it faster if I send out further requests before waiting till the old one gets responded to? Please see my script above, is there a way I can improve the performace? Of course processing power is not limiting here but sending requests simultaniously should improve the speed in my opinion. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want brute force or random?  Below is a sequential brute force method with repeating characters.  The speed of this is going to be largely determined by your server response.  Also note that this would likely generate a denial of service condition very quickly.

```
import itertools
import url

pageChars = 5
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-"

#iterate over the product of alphabet with <pageChar> elements
#this assumes repeating characters are allowed
# Beware this generates len(alphabet)**pageChars possible strings
for chars in itertools.product(alphabet,repeat=pageChars):
    pageString = ''.join(chars)

    urlString = 'https://mydomain.com/' + pageString

    try:
        url = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    except urllib2.HTTPError:
        print('No page at: %s' % urlString)
        continue     

    pageDate = url.read()
    #do something with page data
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to brute force, not random. Sorry for not pointing that out. My script was similar but I thought I could improve the performance by using multiple threads. It turns out that it is even slower!

Comment: Adding threads will only help swamp your server.  Using my example I generated 1,000,000 urls in about .5 seconds on my laptop.  Even with a server running on the localhost the bottleneck will be with the server and network.  Ping your server to get a response time and then multiply that by the number of unique urls you expect.  That would be the best run time you could expect, ignoring all additional factors.